# How to set the acrylic style to window?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, winui-3

I want to create a window with acrylic style. I had read the code on WinUI3 Gallery and tried to use **AddSystemBackdropTarget()** to achieve that.

```
protected override void OnLaunched(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    // m_window = WindowHelper.CreateWindow();
    m_window = new Window();
    Frame rootFrame = GetRootFrame(args);
    // if (m_window.DispatcherQueue != null) // ture
    DesktopAcrylicController acrylicController = new();
    acrylicController.AddSystemBackdropTarget(m_window.As<ICompositionSupportsSystemBackdrop>());
    m_window.Activate();
}
```

PS: I'm using the template of WinUI3 which was created by Visual Studio.

The exception was:
[exception info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X19g.png)

About my machine:
**OS**: Window 11, version 22H2
**Windows SDK**: Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.2

I have noticed that the AddSystemBackdropTarget() method must be called on a thread with a **DispatcherQueue**, so I checked the property to ensure it's not null.
And I also tried **TryEnqueue()** method to add the AddSystemBackdropTarget() task to the DispatcherQueue. But none of them could solve my problem.

Comment: You need a `Windows.System.DispatcherQueue` (specific to Windows) on the thread which is not the same as a `Microsoft.UI.Dispatching.DispatcherQueue` (WinUI3) before you call `AddSystemBackdropTarget`. Check out the offical sample here to create one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/system-backdrop-controller#example-use-mica-in-a-windows-appsdkwinui-3-app

Comment: Thanks, the problem was successfully solved! But could you please explain the difference between Windows.System.DispatcherQueue and Microsoft.UI.Dispatching.DispatcherQueue. I'm still wondering why it worked?

Comment: WinUI3 has a certain level of independence from Windows. It mainly uses it's own dispatcher queue and has its own composition engine (Visual Layer) for most work in the Microsoft.* namespaces. But Acrylic & Mica are 100% specific to Windows as they use WinRT's Visual Layer (same as UPW one) in the Windows.* namespaces https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/composition

Answer (score 1):

Thanks again to [@Simon Mourier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403671/simon-mourier) for his answer. The problem has been solved. To solve this problem, you need to use **CreateDispatcherQueueController()** method which belongs to CoreMessaging.dll. The exception happened because I confused **WinUI3** and **WinRT** visual layer. For more information, please check out the comments above.

**EDIT**ing in those comments:

> You need a `Windows.System.DispatcherQueue` (specific to Windows) on the thread which is not the same as a `Microsoft.UI.Dispatching.DispatcherQueue` (WinUI3) before you call `AddSystemBackdropTarget`. Check out the [official sample here to create one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/system-backdrop-controller#example-use-mica-in-a-windows-appsdkwinui-3-app).

> WinUI3 has a certain level of independence from Windows. It mainly uses its own dispatcher queue and has its own composition engine (Visual Layer) for most work in the `Microsoft.*` namespaces. But Acrylic & Mica are 100% specific to Windows as they use WinRT's Visual Layer (same as UWP one) in the `Windows.*` namespaces https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/composition