# App crashes when setting Acrylic background | WinUI 3

Tags: windows, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I am making a WinUI 3 app in C++. I tried setting the backdrop of the window to acrylic but it does not work. It crashes with the exception "hresult_error" when calling AddSystemBackdropTarget. I could not find out why this is.

Code:

```
void MainWindow::myButton_Click(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&)
    {
        auto m_configurationSource = Microsoft::UI::Composition::SystemBackdrops::SystemBackdropConfiguration();
        auto m_Target = this->try_as<Microsoft::UI::Composition::ICompositionSupportsSystemBackdrop>();
        auto desktopAcrylicController = Microsoft::UI::Composition::SystemBackdrops::DesktopAcrylicController();

        if (m_Target == nullptr) {
            MessageBox(NULL, L":(", L":(", MB_OK);
        }

        desktopAcrylicController.AddSystemBackdropTarget(m_Target); // This is where the error is
        desktopAcrylicController.SetSystemBackdropConfiguration(m_configurationSource);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you debug, you'll see the error is *"0x80070005 : 'Must have a Windows.System.DispatcherQueue on the current thread.'"*.

This is the same issue as here [How to set the acrylic style to window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74591734/how-to-set-the-acrylic-style-to-window)

WinUI3 has a certain level of independence from Windows. It mainly uses it's own dispatcher queue and has its own composition engine ("Visual Layer") for most work in the `Microsoft.*` namespaces. But Acrylic & Mica are 100% specific to Windows as they use WinRT's Visual Layer (same as UWP one) in the `Windows.*` namespaces.

So, you must create a whole shebang to make it work, the official sample is described here 
[Example: Use Mica in a Windows AppSDK/WinUI 3 app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/system-backdrop-controller#example-use-mica-in-a-windows-appsdkwinui-3-app) (don't forget to choose C++/WinRT in the upper right corner to get the code for C++ not for C#)

Comment: Then what does [ConfigBackdrop](https://ghost1372.github.io/winUICommunityCore/themeService/#ConfigBackdrop) do ?

Comment: @Tommy - I have no idea, this is not the official WinUI3 product but some community toolkit